# Spring Boot SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor necessary for inheriting thread context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-mvc

Currently I try to dive deeper into the concurrency model of Spring Boot (servlet stack)

We are using a service that provides some important thread context information (such as current language of an HTTP request) to our service layers. This way we don't have to forward lots of context information from the controller to the service layer and so on. This so called `CurrentThreadContextProviderService` uses the `RequestContextHolder` to get the current request context information for the current thread. It looks like this:

```
@Service
public class CurrentThreadContextProviderService {

/** Returns the current authentication for the current thread context if there is one.
 *
 * @return the current authentication, may be not existing
 * */
public Optional<CustomAuthentication> getAuthentication() {
    Authentication currentAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (!(currentAuthentication instanceof CustomAuthentication)) {
        return Optional.empty();
    } else {
        return Optional.of((CustomAuthentication) currentAuthentication);
    }
    
}
// more methods like the one above
}
```

This works like a charm, but we are facing a problem: some services have to use an async approach of processing business logic. This means that our request thread spawns more child threads to process the request.

The problem then is that our `CurrentThreadContextProviderService` doesn't have access to the current request anymore, at least not by default. I found out that I can make the request inheritable to child threads using the `setThreadContextInheritable` method in a custon `RequestContextFilter` bean. But there is a warning on this page that says that one should not use the ThreadPoolExecutor when using this inheritance mechanism. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.filter/-request-context-filter/set-thread-context-inheritable.html)

My question now is: do I really have to stick with the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` that doesn't reuse threads when using `setThreadContextInheritable(true)`?

And my second question: If we define this SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return asyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myAsyncTaskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("simpleTaskExecutorThread-");
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }
}
```

Will this TaskExecutor also be used when processing parallel HTTP requests in Spring Web Controllers? I have the fear that if using a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor the performance of our web application gets significantly worse.

Comment: I think this is possible. Let's say an event is posted in the controller and the listening for this event is asynchronous. The threads spawned at this point are children of the current main thread. With `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` these threads do eventually end, but it doesn't feel much different from `ThreadPoolExecutor` after all. After all, `ThreadPoolExecutor` also has a `keepalive` parameter. I never felt this was a good way to do things. Why not use the shared variable approach? Just make sure the variables are thread-safe.